# I want to delete the list element at the same time that the game object in the list disappears

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

We are trying to add the ability to lose three child slimes at the same time when attacked by a specific weapon.

Children's slime is managed by List.

List script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChildSlimeList : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private List<GameObject> SlimeChild=new    List<GameObject>();

public void ChildSlimeRandomOff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var SlimeNum = Random.Range(0, SlimeChild.Count);
        GameObject SlimeChildList = SlimeChild[SlimeNum];
        SlimeChildList.SetActive(false);

        SlimeChild.RemoveAt(SlimeNum);
    }
 }
}
```

Child slime script

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using _SlimeCatch.Stage;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = System.Random;

public class ChildrenSlimeWeaponCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private GameObject MolotovCocktail;
public GameObject GameManager;
ChildSlimeList _childSlimeList;
void Start()
{
    //_childSlimeList = GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().SlimeChild();
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    //if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon")) return;
    
    //_childSlimeList.SlimeChild.RemoveAt(this.gameObject);
    
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MolotovCocktail")) 
    {
        GameManager.GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().ChildSlimeRandomOff();
    }

    Destroy(gameObject);//or SetActive(false)
    Destroy(other.gameObject);//or SetActive(false)
    
}
```

}

At this rate, the elements of the slime list of the child attacked by a specific weapon will not be deleted directly. Help me.

State of the game[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9u5f.png)

Comment: any errors in the console¿? Also take into account that with the `Destroy(gameObject)` you are destroying the gameObject where `ChildSlimeList ` monobehaviour lives. So if anything that is not the MolotovCocktail collides, will make the gameobject to be destroyed so the trigger wont be listening anymore

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. The List script is attached to an empty object, and the Child slime script is attached to each child slime.In short, how do you access the List and delete the element containing the directly attacked object in OnCollisionEnter2D ()?I know I can remove it from the List with RemoveAt (), but I don't know how to specify it.

Comment: @eichan114: Why you writing `GameManager.GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().ChildSlimeRandomOff();` and why not `other.gameObject.GetComponent < ChildSlimeList > ().ChildSlimeRandomOff ()`? To me it appears more of a reference problem to which you referring to or held by `GameManager` and which actually collided.

Comment: @nIcEcOw What I'm trying to do is to make three pairs of enemies disappear at the same time. One of them will be the one that was directly attacked, and the other two will be randomly selected.**GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().ChildSlimeRandomOff();** to call the function that randomly selects two bodies. This works perfectly.
The problem is that the number of elements in the list does not decrease when a slime that has been directly attacked disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChildSlimeList : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> SlimeChild=new List<GameObject>();
    
    public void ChildSlimeRandomOff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            var SlimeNum = Random.Range(0, SlimeChild.Count);
            GameObject SlimeChildList = SlimeChild[SlimeNum];
            SlimeChildList.SetActive(false);

            SlimeChild.RemoveAt(SlimeNum);
        }
    }

    public void SlimeColliderDecision(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        SlimeChild.Remove(gameObject);
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using _SlimeCatch.Stage;
using UnityEngine;
using Random = System.Random;

public class ChildrenSlimeWeaponCollider : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject MolotovCocktail;
    public GameObject GameManager;
    ChildSlimeList _childSlimeList;
    void Start()
    {
        //_childSlimeList = GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().SlimeChild();
    }
    
    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        //if (!other.gameObject.CompareTag("Weapon")) return;
        
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MolotovCocktail")) 
        {
            GameManager.GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().SlimeColliderDecision(this.gameObject);
            
            GameManager.GetComponent<ChildSlimeList>().ChildSlimeRandomOff();
        }
        
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

By making this change, we were able to hide three objects and at the same time reduce the number of elements in the list that contain them.

Many thanks to those who gave me tips.